# How can I stop Google crawling webservice URLs?

Tags: html, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am finding that GoogleBot is crawling webservice URLs which are referenced in JavaScript/AJAX code. The URL is already in robots.txt as an exclusion, but Google no longer seems to obey robots.txt when determining what to ***crawl*** - it only seems to use it to know what not to ***index***.

Thankfully these service URLs only return data rather than performing actions but it's messing up the statistics we collect which is highly undesirable. I cannot personally see how Google is even finding out the URL of the webservice unless it crawls arbitrary strings in Javascript code (which seems unlikely?).

For some URLs this also results in me getting LOTS of Elmah error messages from the website which say:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetShortlists'.**" ... as Google tries to *GET* the URL when it only supports *POST*.

The code it's finding the URLs in is as follows:

```
function GetShortlistsForUser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "/WebService/WebService.asmx/GetShortlists",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { /*--CUT--*/ });
        }
    });
```

So should I obfuscate the URL somehow by perhaps replacing the slashes, or is there a better way to stop these getting crawled?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Try break the url format in your javascript codes, e.g,

```
var breaker="x/G";
......
url: "/WebServic"+"e/WebService."+"asm"+breaker+"etshortlists",
```

since Google may use regex to determine which part is url... (I am not sure if this could prevent crawlers, but if it works, you don't need to break it to this extend as it also breaks code reading experience.)

(2) On your server, Google crawler typically use customized agent string, so you can deny it (or ignore it).

Comment: I'm wondering if google is actually evaluating/executing the JS in order to figure out the URLs though? I can't believe it blindly reqests pages based on every string it finds in JS or everyone's server logs would be totally full of rubbish. If so then any obfuscation technique won't actually work.

Comment: @NickG Right. Obfuscation strings is not an ideal solution. So just consider it as an option. The server side control is preferred generally.